# aiohttp error invalid constant string

Tags: python, aiohttp

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import asyncio
import aiohttp

url = "http://eniig.dk"

async def main():
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                try:
                    body = await response.read()
                    print(response.method)
                    print(body)
                except UnicodeDecodeError as msg:
                    print(msg)
                    print(body)
    except Exception as msg:
        print(msg)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

This code gives an error:

`400, message='400, message='invalid constant string''`

If the URL specifies 'https', then everything is OK. But how to avoid an error if the protocol is not known in advance?

What alternatives will advise aiohttp?

**UPD:**
I have not been here for a long time. Forgot to say that the code was run under Debian 8 stable. The problem was solved by replacing the methods ClientSession() and get() by TCPConnector() and request()

Comment: Works fine for me, with the http...

Comment: what version of aiohttp are you using? This one also works fine for me with `aiohttp==2.0.5`

Answer (score 2):

It's looks like a pretty good code.
Worked for me with this versions of `aiohttp`:

- 2.0.7
- 2.0.6
- 2.0.5
- 2.0.4
- 2.0.3
- 2.0.2
- 2.0.1
- 2.0.0